# Transfer sqlite row to new activity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-intent

For a cookbook app I have a screen with a listview of recipe titles a user has saved. When the user clicks on one of the titles (listview item) it will open a new screen and display the full recipe. 
I have stored all the recipe information in a sqlite database. So a row consists of a title, category, imagepath and recipe text. What I can't seem to work out is how I can use the recipe title to display the corresponding recipe text in the new activity.

*So this is the onCreate of activity with the title ListView:*

```
    // Analyze cursor object: Is there data available on the cursor object?
    if (cursor!=null && cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
                // Get information from the cursor object
                String imagePath;
                String titles;
                titles = cursor.getString(0);
                imagePath = cursor.getString(1);

                // Get the titles and image paths from the database
                RecipeDataProvider recipeDataProvider = new RecipeDataProvider(convertSrcToBitmap(imagePath), titles);

                // Add them to the listview
                adapter.add(recipeDataProvider);
            }
            while (cursor.moveToNext());
        }
    }

    // Set onclicklistener for the recipe titles.
    viewTitlesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            // Get the index of the title in the database
            String index = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.recipeTitle)).getText().toString();
            // TODO get corresponding recipe text

            Bundle dataBundle = new Bundle();
            dataBundle.putString("id", index);

            // Go to ShowRecipeActivity
            Intent showIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ShowRecipeActivity.class);
            showIntent.putExtras(dataBundle);
            startActivity(showIntent);
        }
    });
}
```

*This is the activity where I retrieve the data. At the moment it only shows the title of the recipe again:*

```
// Get the recipe title from the previous activity
    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    mRecipeTitle = extras.getString("id");
    recipeTitleView.setText(mRecipeTitle);
// TODO: Get the corresponding recipe text from the database
```

*And this is the cursor method in my DatabaseHelper:*

```
public Cursor getRecipeInfo(SQLiteDatabase db){
    // Create object of Cursor
    Cursor cursor;

    // Create some projections: the needed column names.
    String[] projections = {RecipeContract.NewRecipeInfo.RECIPE_TITLE,
            RecipeContract.NewRecipeInfo.RECIPE_PHOTO, RecipeContract.NewRecipeInfo.RECIPE_TEXT};

    cursor = db.query(RecipeContract.NewRecipeInfo.TABLE_NAME, projections, null, null, null, null, null);

    return cursor;
}
```

I have been stuck on this problem for a while now, I hope you can help me!

Comment: Try it like this. When the listview item is clicked send its postion to the next activity. Make your database query on the second activity based on the received position.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a another activity to implement this. Once you click on the recipe list your `onclick listener` should take you to next `activity`
where you have to pass the `recipe id`.

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
     Intent intent= new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
     intent.putExtra("recipeID", "0000002");
}
```

Comment: I have a new activity, but I'm having troubles with passing the recipe id. I also found some info on using a Hashmap, maybe that would work in my case?

Comment: Do you have key value pair in the data you are passing?

Comment: I'm passing the recipe title, which is in the same row as the recipe text.

Comment: But I can't figure out how I can use this recipe title as a key value pair.

Comment: Your goal is to display title and text below is that right? if yes, Why dont you fetch the columns needed alone from the singe row and present them